# How to close 1st window after opening 2nd window in pygtk

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk, subprocess, pygtk

In my pygtk app, I want to close current window after opening next window.

this is the code which i have written

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# example base.py

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import subprocess

class Base:
    def next(self,widget):
        subprocess.call('fabfile.py', shell=True)
        self.window.destroy()

    def __init__(self):
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.set_size_request(200,200)
        self.button = gtk.Button("Hello World")
        self.button.show()
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.next)
        self.window.add(self.button)
        self.window.show()

    def main(self):
        gtk.main()

print __name__
if __name__ == "__main__":
    base = Base()
    base.main()
```

when I click on `next` button it opens next window but it does not close my current window in background and current window go to hang in background after opening next window.

```
def next(self,widget):
   subprocess.call("scan.py", shell=True)
   self.win.destroy()
```

when i run this code in `window machine` it is not closing existing window and when i run in `Linux machine` it is giving this error.

`/bin/sh: fabfile.py: command not found`

Anyone let me know how to do this.
Thanks...

Comment: Why do you use a subprocess for something like this? You could just  include the source and do something like "self.other_win.show(); self.win.hide();".

Comment: @jku In hiding also have same problem. when i hide current window it goes hide before opening second window and second window takes more time to open

Comment: That doesn't sound like the same problem at all to me? But of course you can show the next window, and only close the old one when the new window gets a signal that it's ready: 'map' signal sounds like a good one to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I hope it will work,

```
import subprocess
proc=subprocess.Popen(["fabfile.py"], bufsize=2048, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.wait()
self.win.destroy()
```

or

```
        import subprocess
        proc=subprocess.Popen(["fabfile.py"], bufsize=2048, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        completed = False
        while not completed:
            if process.poll() is not None:
                completed = True

        print "communicating"
        process.communicate("k")
        print "communicated"
```

subprocess.Popen will open your 2nd window and close after current window.

**Update**

For linux you have to write below code when you will use subprocess call

The script contains CR characters. The shell interprets these CR characters as arguments.

Solution: Remove the CR characters from the script using the following script.

```
with open('beak', 'rb+') as f:
    content = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(content.replace(b'\r', b''))
    f.truncate()
```

for more clarification you can see this **[recorded link](http://asciinema.org/a/5973)**

Comment: It's working in windows system, but in Linux system when I call another py file then it gives me `/bin/sh: fabfile.py: command not found`. it is not opening that file tell me what I do.

Comment: In Linux machine this will happen becoz when you type `fabfile.py` or `/fabfile.py`, it does not read file name correctly, it ignore character. so '/f' is a single character (ASCII Form feed). You need to escape backslash e.g., using a raw string literal r'\f' (two characters).for this i have updated code above use that in linux.

Comment: Thanks @ashish, really u have resolved my problem. I have cleared my doubt from this link or script.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/subprocess.html#convenience-functions

> Run command with arguments. **Wait for command to complete**, then return
>   the returncode attribute.

The call to `subprocess.call` is blocking, `win.destroy` nor any GTK function will be executed until your `scan.py` app has exited. In C, you'd use [g_spawn_async](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html#g-spawn-async) from GLib, you should be able to figure out the Python equivalent. Or use a thread.

Comment: I have tried both the ways(by check_call or by thread) but problem is not solving. I have used code like this `subprocess.check_call(["scan.py", "-l"], shell=True)`. let me know what i do.

Comment: `check_call` won't solve the problem, it's blocking too, as written on the documentation. As I said, try to use [`glib.spawn_async` from the GLib process spawning features](https://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/glib-functions.html#function-glib--spawn-async).

Comment: I tried to use `glib.spawn_sync` but i am not getting solution of this problem, I don't know i wrote code which is correct or wrong becoz it is not giving any error or not solution. please help me, i m irritating so much.

Comment: And it's `glib.spawn_async` (`async`, not `sync`). Asynchronous means it's non-blocking. Synchronous means it's blocking.

Comment: I have edited my post with whole code. i am not able to write correct code of `glib.spawn_async`. plz let me know how to write `spawn_async` and open next window before close.